# Azure Event Hub failed requests

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, cortana-intelligence

I'm sending messages to Event Hub through cURL adding 'Authorization' to the header. cURL returns "201 Created" which indicates that the message should have been created successfully. However, the Event Hub dashboard shows request as failed.

How can I find the reason for failure through Azure?